# stripe error: No such PaymentMethod: 'pm_xxx'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments, e-commerce, laravel-cashier

really struggling to find the error where i missed. I am using Laravel (v8), Vue (v2) and Stripe(v3) for my e-commerce web-app. I implemented stripe in TEST mode successfully and it was working perfectly fine. And when I switched for live mode I am getting the following error: **No such PaymentMethod: 'pm_1Yyl5xC4bpPAffpGV2p0ZL12'.**

Front and backend scripts are as shown below.

```
async mounted(){
        
this.stripe = await loadStripe(process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY);

        const elements = this.stripe.elements()
        this.cardElement = elements.create('card', {
            classes: {
                base: 'bg-gray-100 rounded border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 p-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out'
            }
        })

        this.cardElement.mount('#card-element')
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    },
```

the method pay now method as follows:

```
async processPayment(){
            //send the payment information to Laravel + Stripe

            this.paymentProcessing = true
            this.billingAddressValidations = {}
            this.stripeErrors = null
            const {paymentMethod, error} = await this.stripe.createPaymentMethod(
                'card', this.cardElement, {
                    billing_details: {
                        name: this.card2.fullName,
                    },
                }
            )

            if(error){
                this.paymentProcessing = false
                alert(error.message)
            } else {

                this.shippingAddress.payment_method_id = paymentMethod.id
                this.shippingAddress.amount = this.cart.reduce((acc, item) => acc + this.itemPrice(item) * item.quantity, 0)
                this.shippingAddress.cart = JSON.stringify(this.cart)
                this.shippingAddress.isBillingAddress = this.isBillingAddress
                this.shippingAddress.billingAddress = this.billingAddress
                this.shippingAddress.orderDetails = this.orderDetails


                const res = await this.apiCall('POST','/api/purchase', this.shippingAddress )
                if(res.status === 200 || res.status === 201 ){
                    this.paymentProcessing = false

                    this.$store.commit('updateOrder', res.data)
                    await this.$store.dispatch('clearCart')
                    //this.orderConfirmation(response.data.transaction_id)
                    await this.$router.push({ name: 'order.summary' })
                }
                if(res.status === 206){
                    if(res.data.type === 'billing_address_error') {
                        this.billingAddressValidations = res.data
                    }
                    if(res.data.type === 'stripe_error') {
                        this.stripeErrors = res.data
                    }
                    this.paymentProcessing = false
                }



            }

        },
```

and the Laravel/Cashier backend as follows:

```
public function purchase(Request $request)
    {
        
        $order_number = "JT2070215";


        $user = User::firstOrCreate(
            [
                'email' => $request->input('email')
            ],
            [
                'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(12)),
                'name' => $request->input('first_name') . ' ' . $request->input('last_name'),
                'address' => $request->input('address'),
                'city' => $request->input('city'),
                'line2' => $request->input('line2'),
                'zip_code' => $request->input('post_code'),
            ]
        );

        try {
            $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
            $user->addPaymentMethod($request->input('payment_method_id'));
            $payment = $user->charge(
                $request->input('amount'),
                    $request->input('payment_method_id'),[
                    'currency'=>'GBP',
                    'customer'=>$user->stripe_id
                ],
                
            );

            $payment = $payment->asStripePaymentIntent();

            $order = $user->orders()
                ->create([
                    'transaction_id' => $payment->charges->data[0]->id,
                    'total' => $payment->charges->data[0]->amount,
                    'name' => $request->first_name." ".$request->last_name,
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'address' => $request->address,
                    'city' => $request->city,
                    'country' => $request->country,
                    'post_code' => $request->postal_code,
                    'order_number'=>$order_number
                ]);

    dispatch(new OrderConfirmationEmailJob($order->transaction_id));
            return $order;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage(), 'type'=>'stripe_error'], 206);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“No such...” errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account)

Comment: Yeah I fixed , right you are. when the app was uploaded to the shared hosting it was still saving the test public key that the it was causing an error. Thanks a lot buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are trying to pass the payment_token used in creating the payment method. In order for you to get the id, you will need to retrieve it from the just created payment method.

So this should work.

```
$paymentMethod = $user->addPaymentMethod($request->input('payment_method_id'));

$paymentId = $paymentMethod->id  // use this for the charge
```